# Can t transform int type to time type(my class type)

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, friend-function

I have an application to do that works with time data(hour, minutes, seconds).

Add in the class next operators:
- (binary operator) defined as member function: it returns the difference between the two operands; if operand1 is smaller than operand2, it returns the time 0:0:0

There are working only print functions and toseconds() function.

This is the error:

```
Error   2   error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'const time' to 'long'       47  1   timeex2

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class time { 
    int hour, min, sec;

    void normalize(); // it transforms the sec and min values on the inside of
                      // [0,59] interval and hour values on the inside of
                      // [0, 23] interval.
                      // Ex: the time 25: 79: 80 is transformed in 2 : 20: 20

public:
    time(int=0, int=0, int=0); // values of the members are normalized

    void print1(); // print on the screen the values as hour : min : sec
    void print2(); // print on the screen the values as hour : min : sec a.m. / p.m.

    void operator-(const time&);

    void toseconds() {
        sec=3600*hour+60*min+sec;
        cout << sec;
    }

//  friend time operator+(const time t) {
//      time t1, t2, t3;
//      t3 = t1 + t2;
//      time::normalize();
//      return t3;
//  }

//  friend time operator>(time t1, time t2) {
//      toseconds(t1);
//      toseconds(t2);
//      if (t1 > t2)
//          cout << "\nt1 is bigger\n";
//      else
//          cout << "\nt1 is smaller\n";
//  }

//  friend time operator==(time t1, time t2) {
//      toseconds(t1);
//      toseconds(t2);
//      if (t1 == t2)
//          cout << "\nEqual\n";
//      else
//          cout << "\nNot equal\n";
//  }
};

void time::operator-(const time& t) {
    long a = *this; // The error is here
    long b = (long)t; // The error is here  
    if (a < b)
        cout << "\n0:0:0\n";
    else
        cout << "\nThe difference is " << a-b << endl;
}

time::time(int a, int b, int c) {
    hour = a;
    min = b;
    sec = c;
    normalize();
}

void time::normalize() {
    int s = sec;
    int m = min;
    int h = hour;
    sec = s % 60;
    min = (m + s/60) % 60;
    hour = (h + m/60 + s/3600) % 24;
}

void time::print1() {
    normalize();
    cout << hour << ":" << min << ":" << sec << endl;
}

void time::print2() {
    normalize();
    if (hour >= 13)
        cout << hour%12 << ":" << min << ":" << sec << " p.m." << endl;
    else
        cout << hour << ":" << min << ":" << sec << " a.m." << endl;
}

int main() {
    time t1(12,45,30), t2(0,0,54620), t3;
    t1.print1();
    t2.print1();
    t1.print2();
    t2.print2();
    cout << "\nTime t1 to seconds\n";
    t1.toseconds();
    t1.operator-(t2);
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class time {` in combination is probably not the best idea.

Comment: I think that the problem is in the operator-, you are converting your class to long, but there is no conversion available. I guess you wanted to call toSeconds() or something similar. Regardeless also toSeconds is wrong. You are overwriting seconds without setting to 0 the other 2 values. Most likely the function should calculate and return the seconds without altering the state of the object. Or am I misunderstanding what you wanted to do?

Comment: Operators normally should return a result – and not output *anything* to console.

Comment: @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts You guessed right, I want only to transform to seconds in function toseconds(), no to modify

Comment: @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts And i want to call it in the operator and compare the seconds, I modified to this:int a;
int b;
a=sec=3600*hour+60*min+sec;
b=sec=3600*hour+60*min+sec;
 if (a<b)
 cout << "\n0:0:0\n";
else
 cout<<"\nThe difference is " << a-b << endl;
return 0;

Comment: @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts No errors, but it not take the correct values

Comment: What do you mean "it not take the correct values"?

Comment: @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts It s show always the first message, so practically he don't take values for a and b

Comment: Print the value of a and b and try to understand why they are not the values you expect

Comment: @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts The values not correspond with the entrances from main

Comment: @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts But i can't figure why

Comment: *'I want only to transform to seconds in function toseconds(), no to modify'* – then you should declare the function `const`. And you need a return value, of course...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*this` is a time object, as well as '`' in the following section:

```
void time::operator-(const time& t) {
    long a = *this; // convert *this to long
    long b = (long) t; // convert t to long

    if (a < b)
        cout << "\n0:0:0\n";
    else
        cout << "\nThe difference is " << a - b << endl;
}
```

You can't convert `time` variable type into 'long' variable type, unless you implement 'operator()' for long casting. If you don't want to overload the casting operator for type 'long', you can use a function to convert it for you (like your `toseconds` function, but it must to return the value, and not just print it).

Without casting operator:

```
class time {
private:
    // ...

public:
    // ...
    long to_seconds() const { // the const is necessary so you will be able to use this method ovet the t parameter in the operator- function (because t defined as `const time&`)
        auto  local_sec = 3600 * hour + 60 * min + sec;
        // cout sec; // print the value
        return local_sec; // return the value
    }
    // ...
}

void time::operator-(const time& t) {
    long a = this->to_seconds(); // take the long value from *this object
    long b = t.to_seconds(); // take the long value from t object

    if (a < b)
        cout << "\n0:0:0\n";
    else
        cout << "\nThe difference is " << a - b << " seconds" << endl;
}
```

With `operator()` overloading it'll looks like that:

```
class time {
private:
    // ...

public:
    // ...
    operator long() const; // Declare operator overloading for `long` type
    long to_seconds() const { // the const is necessary so you will be able to use this method ovet the t parameter in the operator- function (because t defined as `const time&`)
        auto local_sec = 3600 * hour + 60 * min + sec;
        // cout sec; // print the value
        return local_sec; // return the value
    }
    // ...
}

time::operator long() const {
    return to_seconds(); // return the desired long value in cast procedure
}

void time::operator-(const time& t) {
    long a = *this; // cast *this object from `time` type into `long` type
    long b = t; // cast t object from `time` type into `long` type

    if (a < b)
        cout << "\n0:0:0\n";
    else
        cout << "\nThe difference is " << a - b << " seconds" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually, operators should return a result:

```
time time::operator-(const time& t);
```

Then inside your operator, you cast to `long`:

```
long a=*this;
long b=(long)t;
```

Solely: There isn't any such cast operator!

Such casts exist natively only for from one basic data type (`int`, `unsigned long`, `char`, `double`, ...) to another. If any other data type is involved, cast operator must be defined explicitly.

So: 
    class ime
    {
    public:
        explicit operator long()
        {
            return 3600L*hour + 60L*min + sec;
            //         ^          ^
            // using long literals assures that hour and min will be converted
            // to long as well before multiplication - then as other summands
            // are long already, sec will be converted to, too. 
        }
    };

With that, you now *can* cast to void. By the way: the `explicit` keyword assures that you need to cast explicitly, otherwise, it will be applied implicitly in appropriate context:

```
time t;
long l0 = t;                    // possible only without keyword
long l1 = static_cast<long>(t); // required with (alternatively C-style cast)
```

Now you would construct a new time object, though, to return as a result:

```
a -= b;
return a < 0 ? time(0, 0, 0) : time(a / 3600, a / 60 % 60, a % 60);
```

Operators shouldn't output anything, instead, you'd do that on the results returned.

One problem would be, though, that from result `operator-`, you couldn't distinguish if both time values were equal before or the first operator was less.

So you'd need to compare *before*:

```
time t1, t2;
if(t1 < t2)
    std::cout << "\n0:0:0\n";
else
    std::cout << "\nThe difference is " << static_cast<long>(t1 - t2) << std::endl;
```

As you see, any output is done *outside* the operators... Of course, this requires an appropriately defined `bool time::operator<(time const& other);` or alternatively the free-standing variant `bool operator<(time const& x, time const& y);` (which is the one I personally would prefer).